# SQL Developer delete a row using join command

Tags: oracle, join, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-delete, delete-row

i am using the below command to delete REL_CLIENT_CAT table using the JOIN query. But facing the below error in the console. the given query is not working properly when i run in sql developer.

```
delete RL_CLIENT_CAT rlcc 
 join CLIENT_CATEGORY cc on cc.client_id = rlcc.client_category_id
 where rlcc.clientId='298860' and cc.code='client1'
```

the error message i got

```
delete RL_CLIENT_CAT rlcc 
 left outer join CLIENT_CATEGORY cc on cc.client_id = rlcc.client_category_id
  where rlcc.clientId='298860' and cc.code='client1'
Error at Command Line : 10 Column : 2
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DELETE` using `join` is not possible in oracle. Instead you can use the following query:

```
DELETE RL_CLIENT_CAT RLCC
 WHERE RLCC.CLIENT_CATEGORY_ID IN (
    SELECT CC.CLIENT_ID
      FROM CLIENT_CATEGORY CC
     WHERE CC.CODE = 'client1'
)
   AND RLCC.CLIENTID = '298860';
```

or you can use correlated subquery using `EXISTS` as follows:

```
DELETE RL_CLIENT_CAT RLCC
 WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
      FROM CLIENT_CATEGORY CC
     WHERE RLCC.CLIENT_CATEGORY_ID = CC.CLIENT_ID
       AND CC.CODE = 'client1'
)
   AND RLCC.CLIENTID = '298860';
```